# Call Skype ID from Twilio?

Tags: twilio, skype

Is that possible to call a Skype ID (not a Skype number) using Twilio client application? If possible then how to accomplish this? Please help me if anyone have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that Twilio Client can only call phone numbers or other Twilio Client IDs and not a Skype ID.

Comment: is this still the case?

Comment: Hi @MasterScrat, yep. Skype is a completely different system to Twilio and there is no connection between them.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by signing up for a SkypeIn number, which is just a regular phone number that will call you on Skype. You can then use this phone number with Twilio.

More information on SkypeIn:
https://secure.skype.com/skypein/start